# Using react-router useHistory hook to navigate to current route with new query params

Tags: reactjs, tabs, navigation, router

I want to use search params to navigate between tabs in the same route.
With:

```
history.push({
  pathname: "/reservations",
  search: "?tab=3",
});
```

the url in the browser changes to '/reservations?tab=3' but the component isn't re-rendered and I can't get the new "tab" search param value to show the 3rd tab.

I believe this happens because there is no change in the route, only in the params. How can I 'force' the component to update?